# Rails: how to delete associated model on "accepts_nested_attributes_for " if all attributes are blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Book` model that accepts_nested_attributes_for `book_versions`:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :book_versions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_versions
  validates_associated :book_versions
```

It works fine and dandy when a user creates a Book with associated book versions. However, when a user edits a book it doesn't work as well. I want it so that when the user edits a book and clears all the nested form fields for book_versions for the book version to be deleted.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add an after save callback in the BookVersion model which will destroy the record if empty. sketched out below.

```
class BookVersion < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save :delete_if_empty_attr

   def delete_if_empty_attr
     if foo.empty? && bar.empty?
       self.destroy
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_versions, reject_if: :all_blank
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html